# How will an overloaded ostream operator interpret this expression of overloaded operators?

Tags: c++

This question may have been asked before, but I wasn't quite sure what to search for - at least in regard to what terms to search for.

In any case, this is my problem. Consider this code snippet:

```
int main()
{ 
   myArray list_Array(10);

   int i;

   cout << "list_Array : ";
   for (i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
       cout << list_Array[i] <<" ";
   cout<< endl;

   ...
```

Here, `myArray` class is really just an array with extra safeguards such as bound checking. Here, the `<<` operator is overloaded in addition to the `[]` operator being overloaded. I've already overloaded the latter operator, and I started writing the implementation to overload `<<`.

However, I started wondering how isStream will interpret this part of the expression: `list_Array[i]`.

To explain, I could typically overload this operator with something like this:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& isObject, someObject& x)
{
    isObject << x.length;
    return isObject;
}
```

In this case, what I'm passing is not purely the object itself. Instead, I'm wanting to print `list_Array[i]`.

For sake of detail, this is the overall functionality of that overload:

```
const int& myArray::operator[](int index) const
{
    return list[index];
}
```

That said, how is this expression handled? Which overload will be applied first? If the overloaded `<<` operator is applied first, do I need to modify the parameter I'm passing into the `<<` implementation?

Any constructive input is appreciated.

NOTE: `list` is a dynamic array.

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking about. Are you talking about `<<` or `>>`?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong function. I'm talking about <<. I will edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That said, how is this expression handled? Which overload will be applied first? If the overloaded << operator is applied first, do I need to modify the parameter I'm passing into the << implementation?

This has nothing to do with overloading. It's operator precedence, and it doesn't change whether your operators are overloaded or not.

`[]` goes first, and the result is passed to your overloaded `<<` operator. This is true regardless of overloading; the operands of an operator can't affect its precedence.

> Obviously, the << operator is overloaded in addition to the [] operator being overloaded

That's not obvious at all. You would only need to overload `<<` if your array contains some kind of object that ostreams don't already have an `operator<<` for. Your overloaded `[]` appears to return `int`s, so there is absolutely no reason write your own `<<` operator for working with `ostream`.

> In this case, what I'm passing is not purely the object itself. Instead, I'm wanting to print list_Array[i], which is an operation on my object.

You're not "printing an operation". The operation happens, independent of the printing, and the result of the operation is passed to your `<<`. The result would be the `int` returned by your `operator[]`.

Comment: Your second statement makes sense to me. However, IntelliSense seems to have a different opinion, and this is what is particularly puzzling me - hence I asked this question. In any case, your points answered my questions.

Comment: I cannot comment on IntelliSense or how you're interpreting its "opinion". You're going to have to be much clearer than that.

Comment: What prompted me to ask this question is IntelliSense's error that states: no operator "<<" matches these operands, which are std::ostream <<. So I figured something was amiss with my understanding of expression I posted (which seems to be clear).